# Build an Array used to get a menu tree - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, menu

I have looked for a solution to this question & I only found solutions to directly display a menu, as I need the menu-structure in the backend for editing purpose as well and to learn the most efficient way of programming I want not to directly print the menu but fill an Array with a tree structure.

My goal is to get something like this:

```
$items[$itemId] = new ItemObject;
$items[$itemId][$childItemId] = new ItemObject;
$items[$itemId] = new ItemObject;
$items[$itemId][$childItemId] = new ItemObject;
$items[$itemId][$childItemId][$childItemId] = new ItemObject;
```

The data is stored in a MySQL-Database and is not ordered as one can change the parent Item at any time.

Database example:

```
MenuID    |    MenuName    |    MenuParentId

1         |    Paintings   |    0
2         |    Cars        |    3
3         |    Vehicles    |    0
4         |    Boats       |    3
5         |    Audi        |    2
6         |    Honda       |    2
7         |    A3          |    5
8         |    TDI         |    7
```

I do work with objects, and I do want to get an Array filled as described before, it is no problem if I only have 1 Sublevel or if I'd know how many Sublevels are given but that's not the case as one should be able to add as many Sublevels as one wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I would not refer to things by their id because that makes it rather hard to know when reading the code exactly what menu item does things.  I would use PHP's associative arrays and give them an explicit key.  You'd have to make sure each key is unique, but you can also make the unique key different than what is displayed, so if you have two different menu items called honda, one would be honda_cars and the other honda_streetfighter but both's value be 'honda'.

Example: instead of seeing $items[2][5][7][8], you could see $items['cars']['audi']['a3']['tdi'], which is a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar problem recently, and we searched for some good solution, since we had a lot of sub-levels and a lot of data.
I suggest for you to go look into [Nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

I won't explain it to you here, you can find some way better articles that i could do out there on the web.

Advantages :

- Faster for searching into the tree
- Can handle easily unlimited levels

Disadvantages :

- Slower for insert/update/delete
- Harder to understand than adjacency list model

I guess there are way more, but those are the one i can tell after using it.

If you want some more information about managing hierachical data, you can go look [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), it gives some good informations about using both solutions in MySQL(all credits to its author).

Hope it helps, and if you find some other way around, let us know !

Answer (score 0):

A table structure like the one you posted can build a hierarchy with a recursive algorithm like the following:

```
//This class represents a menu object which can have several children (sub menu levels)
//and can be a sub menu by itself
class ItemObject {
    public $id, $name, $children = array();
    //Creates a new item object and if there is an sql result array given, the method 
    //parseChildren is called directly
    public function __construct($id, $name, array $sqlArray = null) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        if($sqlArray !== null) {
            $this->parseChildren($sqlArray);
        }
    }
    //This function iterates through the given array and creates new child nodes if
    //the MenuParentID for the current row matches the id of the current ItemObject.
    //Because this method will be called from the constructor and also creates new 
    //item objects which also causes the constructor of the child object to be exe-
    //cuted, this is a recursive algorithm
    public function parseChildren(array $results) {
        foreach($results as $value) {
            if($this->id === (int)$value['MenuParentID']) {
                $this->children[] = new ItemObject((int)$value['MenuID'],
                  $value['MenuName'], $results);
            }
        }
    }
}
//This class is used for the top level (ID 0) with a special constructor.
class ItemObjectContainer extends ItemObject {
    public function __construct(array $sqlArray) {
        $this->id = 0;
        $this->parseChildren($sqlArray);
    }
}

//This function creates an array from an Mysqli result object, can be altered
//if for example PDO is used
function toArray(mysqli_result $result) {
    return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
//This function finally creates an array of ItemObjects with their correct hierarchy
function createMenu(mysqli_result $result) {
    $resultArray = toArray($result);
    $menuObject = new ItemObjectContainer($resultArray);
}
```

I for myself prefer recursive approaches but one has to decide whether he wants to use them or not. An extension to the ItemObject and the ItemObjectContainer classes could be a recursive method which prints the navigation to the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few links that may help you:

- [Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/)
- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

In both articles are explained two most common approaches, The **Adjacency List Model** ( model that you are using ), and **Nested Set Model**. For larger set of data i will recommend Nested model, and for something smaller Adjacency Model will be fast enough.

I guess you want to create tree structure of objects and fill them with data from the database. PHP has implemented everything you need to help you do that. First method that is helpful is [mysqli_result::fetch_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php). It will return the row of the result set as an object, but more important here, you can instantiate an object of your own that will be filled with row of data from the result set. This example will recursively create `MenuItem` objects, each object will hold the data from the database and will have an array of child items ( if they exists ). If you plan to extend the database with fields like `MenuHref` or `MenuDescription`, that properties will be added to objects also. Example of MenuItem object structure:

```
MenuItem Object(
    [MenuID] => 0
    [children] => Array (
         [0] => MenuItem Object (
                [MenuID] => 1
                [MenuName] => Paintings
                [MenuParentId] => 0
                )
         [3] => MenuItem Object (
                [MenuID] => 3
                [MenuName] => Vehicles
                [MenuParentId] => 0
                [children] => Array (
                     [2] => MenuItem Object (
                           [MenuID] => 2
                           [MenuName] => Cars
                           [MenuParentId] => 3
                           [children] => Array 
                               (
                                  ...
                               )
                           )
                     [4] => MenuItem Object (
                           [MenuID] => 4
                           [MenuName] => Boats
                           [MenuParentId] => 3
                           )
                     )
                )
        )
)
```

At some point you will want to print the menu. PHP has [magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__toString()` that is perfect for that. Whenever is object treated like a string, __toString() method is initiated. Since all objects have this method, PHP will recursively collect the string output from each object, and will return the result, and that really makes things easier.

```
class MenuItem {
    
    function __construct( $id = 0 ) 
    {
        if ( !isset( $this->MenuID ) ) $this->MenuID = $id;
    }
    
    function get_children() 
    {
        global $mysqli;
        $result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE MenuParentId={$this->MenuID}" );

        while ( $row = $result->fetch_object( 'MenuItem' ) )
            $this->children[ $row->MenuID ] = $row->get_children();
        
        return $this;
    }
    
    function __toString()
    {
        if ( isset( $this->children ) ) {
            $output = "<li><a>{$this->MenuName}</a><ul>" . implode( $this->children ) . "</ul></li>";
        } else {
            $output = "<li><a>{$this->MenuName}</a></li>";
        }
        return $output;
    }
    
}

// build menu
$menu = new MenuItem();
$menu->get_children();  // e.g. $menu->get_children( 3 ); for partial build

// show menu
echo '<ul>' . implode( $menu->children ) . '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for you help, it helped me very much on my way of understanding PHP, and I came to a solution which I like.
I want to share my way of it with you, I think it is quite easy to understand but still does it's job.

First of all I needed a Class fitting my Needs, as I am jusing a multi class system I have one model class which defines the fields and does some other stuff, too.

Here is the core of that file:

```
class Menus{

    // Defining the Fields of this class, which are just the field names in our database (I slightly hanged them)

    private $menus_id;
    private $menus_name;
    private $menus_parent_id;

    // This is not actualy a field in our database but will be later used as a container for the child elements

    private $menus_child_obj;

    // Constructor fills the class with all available data

    public function __construct($arr = array()) {
        foreach ( $arr as $key => $val ) {
            if (property_exists ( get_class($this), $key )) {
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    // This function allows to change data after the object is bulid, quite easy

    public function autoSetter($fieldName,$value) {
        $this->$fieldName = $value;
    }

    // This function allows accessing the data of the object

    public function autoGetter($fieldName) {
        return $this->$fieldName;
    }

}
```

Next, there is a class which prepares Data for output, but I wont get into detail here because it is not the topic of this question.

```
class MenusClass extends MenusADB{

    // This is the function which handles the output for me, I'll skip most of the content here

    function getMenusUl(){

         $menusObj = parent::getMenusObjADB(0);

         // Handle content

    }

}
```

We finaly get to the point where the magic happens, you may notice another class beeing extendet, I wont show it because all it does according to this topic is establishing a PDO connection.

```
class MenusADB extends RootClass{

    // This are some variables used in some other functions in this class aswell, it is not neccessery to do it this way, but as it makes things way more easy in many other cases I just show it to you

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = strtolower(basename(__FILE__, 'ADB.php'));
        $this->primaryKey = strtolower(basename(__FILE__, 'ADB.php')."_id");
    }

    function set($obj){
        return new $this->table($obj);
    }

    // Finaly we get to the recursive function which bulids the wanted oject

    function getMenusObjADB($id){
    try{

        // This is the SQL query which gets all records that have the wanted parent, this allows us to call it with the id of the menu item we are currently building, wich ends up in a loop, till no records are left

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("
                                SELECT
                                  *
                                FROM
                                  {$this->table}
                                WHERE
                                  menus_parent_id = :id
                                ");
        $stmt->bindValue('id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();

        // This is the loop which gets all the objects

        while($res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            // First we set a new Array with the object filled with all the information of the currently looped Item

            $ret[] = $this->set($res);

            // Next we check if this Item has children by calling this same function but this time with the id parameter of the item we have just build

            if($this->getMenusObjADB($res[$this->primaryKey]) != null){

                // If so we add them to our container we defined in the first class, therefore we need to acces the Arraykey we put our current item in, this is done by first using end($ret) and key($ret), for more details pleasy visit php.net

                end($ret);
                $ret[key($ret)]->autoSetter('menus_child_obj', $this->getMenusObjArrADB($res[$this->primaryKey]));
            }
        }

        // At this point we check if the query has got any results (If there have been items with the wanted parent_id)

        if(empty($ret)){
            return null;
        }

        // If so we return our newly build object

        return $ret;

    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        print "<pre>";
        print_r($ex);
        print "</pre>";
        exit;
    }
}

}
```

I hope this helps people looking for a solution, and again thank all of you by helping me finding my path by suppling this much help!

Greating

Chris

Answer (score 0):

```
// Another way much simpler

// Menu Array multidimensional
$menu = array(
    'page_1' => array(
        'text' => 'page 1',
        'url' => 'page_1.html',
        'children' => array()
    ),
    'page_2' => array(
        'text' => 'page 2',
        'url' => 'page_2.html',
        'children' => array(
            'sub_menu_1' => array(
                'text' => 'sub menu 1',
                'url' => 'sub_menu_1.html',
                'children' => array(
                    'sub_menu_1_2' => array(
                        'text' => 'sub menu 12',
                        'url' => 'sub_menu_1_2.html',
                        'children' => array()
                    )
                )
            ),
            'sub_menu_2' => array(
                'text' => 'sub menu 2',
                'url' => 'sub_menu_2.html',
                'children' => array()
            ),
            'sub_menu_3' => array(
                'text' => 'sub menu 3',
                'url' => 'sub_menu_3.html',
                'children' => array()
            ),
            'sub_menu_4' => array(
                'text' => 'sub menu 4',
                'url' => 'sub_menu_4.html',
                'children' => array()
            )
        )
    ),
    'page_3' => array(
        'text' => 'page 3',
        'url' => 'page_3.html',
        'children' => array()
    )
);

// Make menu
function makeMenu($menu_array,$is_sub = false,$list=['ul','li']){
    $attr  = (!$is_sub) ? ' class="menu"' : ' class="submenu"';
    $child = NULL;
    $menu = "<{$list[0]}{$attr}>";
    foreach($menu_array as $id => $items){
        foreach($items as $key => $val){
            if( is_array($val) ) {
                if ( !empty($val) )  {
                    $child = makeMenu($val,true,$list);
                }
            } else {
                $$key = $val;
            }
        }//foreach
        $menu .= "<{$list[1]}>";
            $menu .= '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$text.'</a>';
            $menu .= $child; // Sub Menu
        $menu .= "</{$list[1]}>";
        unset($child);
    }//foreach
    $menu .= "</{$list[0]}>";
    return $menu;
}

// retrieve the desired page with the shaft
function makeSubMenu($menu, $key) {
   return makeMenu(array($menu[$key]));
}

// chain Article
function chainItem(array $array, $unset = '' ){
    $ds = array();
    if ( is_array($array) )
        foreach((array)$unset as $arr) unset($array[$arr]);
        foreach($array as $key=>$value)
            if (!is_array($value)) $ds[$key] = $value;
    return $ds;
}

// Build walk recursive -> single array insert database MySql
function walkRecursive($array, $ordId = true, $unset=[], $children = 'children',  $i = 1, $parent = 0, &$res = [] ) {
    if ( !is_array($array) ) return array();
    foreach(array_values($array) as $key=>$arr) {
        $das = array( 
            'id' => $id = $ordId ? $arr['id'] : $i++,
            'parent' => $parent
        );
        $res[] = array_merge($das,chainItem($arr,$unset));
        if( isset($arr[$children]) ) {
            walkRecursive($arr[$children], $ordId, $unset, $children, $i, $id, $res );
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

echo makeMenu($menu);

// Result of the print :

<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="page_1.html">page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="page_2.html">page 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="sub_menu_1.html">sub menu 1</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="sub_menu_1_2.html">sub menu 12</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sub_menu_2.html">sub menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sub_menu_3.html">sub menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sub_menu_4.html">sub menu 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="page_3.html">page 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>



// Build walk recursive -> single array insert database MySql
header("Content-type: text/plain");
print_r( walkRecursive($menu,false,['parent','id']) );
// Print array -> Result:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [text] => page 1
            [url] => page_1.html
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 0
            [text] => page 2
            [url] => page_2.html
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 2
            [text] => sub menu 1
            [url] => sub_menu_1.html
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent] => 3
            [text] => sub menu 12
            [url] => sub_menu_1_2.html
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent] => 2
            [text] => sub menu 2
            [url] => sub_menu_2.html
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent] => 2
            [text] => sub menu 3
            [url] => sub_menu_3.html
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent] => 2
            [text] => sub menu 4
            [url] => sub_menu_4.html
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 0
            [text] => page 3
            [url] => page_3.html
        )

)
```